# Clarification on the new Quorum and Convention badges

Tags: support, badges

I noticed that two new badges have been added to Stack Exchange: Quorum and Convention.

The rule for Quorum is:

> One post with score of 2 on meta

and for Convention, it is:

> 10 posts with score of 2 on meta

Just for clarification, what is meant by the word "posts"? Is it for both questions and answers? Are comments included?

Comment: Looks like you just got *Quorum*!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's questions and answers only.

Comment: Not to drag up an old answer, but can you confirm this? I have over 10 answers on meta with a score of 2 or greater, but I don't have this badge and thus can't nominate myself for the current election.

Comment: @Adam - badges are awarded in batches, looks like the latest one gave you your convention badge.

Comment: @KevinMontrose How often those batches occur?