# This tag needs some [clarification]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, burninate-request, meta-tags

The tag [clarification](/questions/tagged/clarification) seems to be useless.

When looking at the questions, I see two main use cases:

- as a *meta-tag* for questions where the author wants to have something explained
- similar to [comments](/questions/tagged/comments) or [edits](/questions/tagged/edits) (requesting clarification from the author)

The tag has also no tag wiki. With 45 questions only, the burnination should not be problematic.

In my opinion, this tag has no real use. It is ambiguous at best and a meta tag at worst.

Should we <s>destroy it</s> kill it with fire?

> **Edit:** After almost one week there was no disagreement with this request. If nobody complains within the next approx. two days, I will start removing the tag.

Comment: how do you remove a tag? Going into individual question and untag it?

Comment: @Ooker see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags) but **do not start removing the tag yet**. I intentionally want to wait some time so that users could respond and defend the tag. Also one should not remove the tag from more than four questions (approx.) at a time.

Comment: It's been a week since this request was filed; since no objections were posted, I think it's OK to burninate.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog I agree and will start removing the tag (always 2-3 at a time) over the next days/weeks. Feel free to help me.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard my first edit to add the tag in this post was just for fun, but now I think for burnimate requests we should really tag the tags in question. For tags with lots of questions that even a group of people wouldn't be able to finish it, I think it's best to edit its wiki to say that the tag is in a process of burnimation. If one click on it they would see the post about burnimating them.

Comment: @Ooker I have just done so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This tag has been *burninated*!**

Users will no longer be able to ask for [clarification](/questions/tagged/clarification).

Thanks to everyone who helped removing this tag!

[image]

Answer (score 9):

### Yes, burn it.

The name is (ironically) **unclear**, and very likely to be misused by inexperienced askers who are (like many askers) seeking "clarification" on some issue. That's obviously a bad use of the tag. This use being so widespread, and natural enough given the tag name, makes the tag not worth keeping around just for some posts which are somehow *about* clarifications, e.g. clarifications to UI or clarification requests on posts.

Answer (score 2):

In the process of removing the tag, I propose to tag questions having issue with language with [language-usage](/questions/tagged/language-usage). There are cases that the language usage can be interpreted differently by different people, therefore require the OPs to ask for... clarification. For example, in the question [Clarification on the new Quorum and Convention badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72080/260800), the OP has trouble with the word "post", so they need a clarification.